# Any Specific Term For Hiring Process Via Being Accommodated Together

Tags: word-choice

I heard there exists some peculiar cultural hiring process of Asian countries such as taking possible applicants together and let them have one or two days of shared accommodation with human-resource affiliates to assess general aspects of applicants to cope with given situation or social intelligence of them.

Any specific English word to refer to this similar concept of process?

Comment: What's the Asian term for this practice? (It might help with finding an English translation.)

Comment: @Lawrence 合宿面接where 合 denotes for together like co as a prefix in Latin and 宿denotes for sleeping and last two words for interview.

Comment: Sorry, nothing comes quickly to mind. It sounds like a camp of sorts. Google Translate produces "habitat access", which doesn't quite hit the mark. The generic term could be something along the lines of a *multi-day interview*, but that leaves the 'stay together' part unspecified.

Comment: @Lawrence As you correctly remarked, the core concept of this practice is to make them to share their daily life together to deal with some sort of given task and also reveal their privates somewhat transparently to know the applicants more frankly (besides of its appealing uncomfortableness). Any similar hiring process conducted in the United States have you heard of? If so, it might be much easier to approximate.

Comment: sounds a bit like a company retreat, except for applicants....applicant retreat?

Comment: @depperm That sounds plausible unless the main goal of it is not teambuilding but assessing

Comment: @Daschin 'Reveal their privates' may not mean what you think it does...

Comment: @Spagirl then again, maybe it's _exactly_ what she meant...

Comment: @MikeHarris no.. it was intended far more moderates..

Comment: will never use the plural form of that word ever.. sorry for all of your misunderstandings

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could say :

*The applicants were subjected to a **Big Brother-style interview process**.*

> Big Brother is a reality game show franchise created by John de Mol, originally broadcast in the Netherlands and subsequently syndicated internationally. As of 11 November 2016, there have been 387 seasons of Big Brother in over 54 franchise countries and regions.
>
> In the show, contestants called "housemates" (or "house guests") live together in a specially-constructed house that is isolated from the outside world. Housemates are voted out (usually on a weekly basis) until only one remains and wins the cash prize. During their stay in the house, contestants are continuously monitored by live television cameras as well as personal audio microphones.
>
> English-language editions of the program are often referred to as "BB"
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Brother_(franchise))

Comment: I love your suggestion. Thx